# MVT on convex sets. (constant function theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: S → R$ be differentiable with $S ⊂ R^n$
. Furthermore let $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ S$.
Show that if $S$ is convex, then $f$ does not depend on $x_1$ (meaning $f(a) = f(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ only differ
in the first component). Is this still true if $S$ is not convex?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Enough if the Intersections of $S$ with the lines along the $x_1$ axis are connected.